# How to implement select2 with lock selection?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, jquery-select2

I am trying to use select2 with one disabled value.

I am trying to implement it like

```
$('#select_currency').select2('data', preloaded_data);
```

I have been reading about **Lock selections** but I am not able to implement it, could you please someone let me know how to implement it or is there any tutorial about it.

Answer (score 7):

You can easely add `locked="locked"` if you use v3.5 http://select2.github.io/select2/#locked-selections.

But in v.4.x this functionality is removed.

I've found solution (or hack:) ) for v.4.x, a little bit dirty with error in console, but it works. Anyway it is best solution what I've found. Check my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/o3s3y42e/4/

Answer (score 3):

And in a select dropdown you can just add the `locked="locked"` attribute.

```
<select id="sharewith" multiple="true">
  <option value="self" selected="selected" locked="locked">myself</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just pass all items you want to lock, e.g

```
$('#select_currency').select2('data', [{id:'myr', text:'Malaysia Ringgit', locked:true}]);
```

Comment: Is it works with select2 v.4.x?
I'v been trying with data pass and select option attribute 'locked' but without any reslts.

Comment: It should work if it's not changed from v3.5. http://select2.github.io/select2/#locked-selections

Comment: Add support back for locked options (4.x): https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3339