# select2 multiselect: disable (lock) some of the selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, multi-select

I have a select dropdown in my code like below. I want to keep some preselected options in there. Some of the preselected options should be FIXED so users can not change them. In order to do this I wrote the following code:

```
<select id="select2-multiple" name="users" multiple="multiple" style="width: 50%">
    <option value="4">Admin</option>
    <option value="5">Manager</option>
    <option disabled="disabled" selected value="6">User</option>
    <option selected value="7">ReadOnly User</option>
    <option disabled="disabled" selected value="8">Assistant Manager</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#select2-multiple').select2();
    });
</script>
```

The preselected options are displayed with no issue. But the ones with `disabled="disabled"` can still be removed from the list. How do I prevent removal of those options?

Answer (score 2):

I find it. I needed to use the `locked` feature of select2. So all I had to do is to change my code in the question to this:

```
<select
  id="select2-multiple"
  name="users"
  multiple="multiple"
  style="width: 50%"
>
  <option value = "4">Admin</option>
  <option value = "5">Manager</option>
  <option locked="locked" selected value = "6">User</option>
  <option selected value = "7">ReadOnly User</option>
  <option locked="locked" selected value = "8">Assistant Manager</option>
</select>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select2-multiple').select2();
});
</script>
```

So basically use `locked` instead of disabled. However, I was using select2 version 3.2 initially and this did not work in there. I had to upgrade to 3.5.4 in order to use this feature.

The documentation can be found here:

http://select2.github.io/select2/#locked-selections

I found this SOF thread pretty helpful aswell:

[how to implement select2 with lock selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564425/how-to-implement-select2-with-lock-selection)

Comment: Can you provide documentation for `locked`?