# Select2, Fixed Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm wondering if there is a way to have fixed options on a multi-select select2 field without being able to remove them from the field.

Comment: Answered -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/48111387/6736212

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selected` with `disabled`

```js
$('select').select2({
  width: 'resolve',
  placeholder: 'This is my placeholder',
  disabled: true
});
console.log($('select').val())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select style="width: 75%" multiple>
  <option selected>option1</option>
  <option selected>option2</option>
  <option selected>option3</option>
</select>
```

To send the values ​​you will have to use javascript manually.

Comment: This disables the whole field. What I'm looking for is the option1 to be fixed or locked and be able to interact with the rest of the option (add/remove)